# Is there a way to check whether a given pid matches any process in kernel space?

Tags: c, kernel, system-calls, pid

Is there a way to check whether a given PID matches any process in kernel space?

I am building a system call that changes the weight of custom weighted round robin scheduler.

I would like to do a check before calling `find_task_by_vpid(pid)` to avoid calling that function if the PID is invalid (i.e. there is no process that has this PID value).

This is because if an invalid PID is used, my virtual machine crashes. So I would like to do a check and return an error value of `-ESRCH` back to user space.

Is there a checking function for that?

Or is it possible to check whether or not `find_task_by_vpid(pid) == NULL` to determine if PID is valid or not? I couldn't find a documentation that specifies what the return is for `find_task_by_vpid(pid)` when `pid` is invalid.

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(set_wrr_weight, pid_t, pid, int, weight){
   struct sched_wrr_entity *wrr_se;
   // I want to do a check here to see if given pid is valid or not
   wrr_se = &find_task_by_vpid(pid)->wrr;
   wrr_se->wrr_weight = weight;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) What kernel version are you on? 2) I believe `rr_se` is supposed to be `wrr_se`? 3) What's `sched_wrr_entity`? That doesn't exist AFAIK, and neither does the `wrr` field on `task_struct`. Do you actually *need* the task struct to use it in your syscall or not?

Comment: Kernel 4.19.105; I am building a custom weighted round robin task scheduler, so wrr_se and sched_wrr_entity are customly added to the kernel; Sched_wrr_entity contains the field "struct list_head list; unsigned int wrr_weight; unsigned int time_slice". So I would need to access and change wrr_weight for that particular process using the syscall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the return value of `find_task_by_vpid()` should be enough to ensure the `pid` is valid. If it wasn't, it wouldn't have had an associated `task_struct` in the first place. If you need a confirmation, this is exactly how the [`getsid` syscall](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.105/source/kernel/sys.c#L1116) handles the PID passed from userspace:

```
// ...
    retval = -ESRCH;
    p = find_task_by_vpid(pid);
    if (!p)
        goto out;
// ...
out:
    rcu_read_unlock();
    return retval;
}
```

There's a different problem in your code though: as far as I can tell, you aren't handling the `task_struct` properly. You should use [`find_get_task_by_vpid()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.105/source/kernel/pid.c#L355) instead of `find_task_by_vpid()`. This function will call [`get_task_struct()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.105/source/include/linux/sched/task.h#L91) for you, incrementing the `task_struct` refcount to avoid race conditions (since as it seems from your code, your syscall can sleep). After that, you can use [`put_task_struct()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.105/source/include/linux/sched/task.h#L95) to decrement the refcount.

Something like this:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(set_wrr_weight, pid_t, pid, int, weight) {
    struct sched_wrr_entity *wrr_se;
    struct task_struct *tsk;

    tsk = find_get_task_by_vpid(pid);
    if (!tsk)
        return -ESRCH;

    wrr_se = &tsk->wrr;
    wrr_se->wrr_weight = weight;

    put_task_struct(tsk);
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, I don't know if you are doing `wrr_se = &tsk->wrr;` because you need it somewhere else in the code, but if you don't, then you should be able to set the `weight` directly doing `tsk->wrr.weight = weight;`.